# Unbinding jQuery event handlers when a KnockoutJs view is unloaded

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I have a simple app with two views, one "app" model and two view models. I am interested in working out how to unbind jQuery events.

The app view model has this property:

```
var self = this;    
self.viewModel = ko.observable(null);
```

The most important HTML snippets resides in the master template and that is:

```
        <!-- ko if: viewModel -->
    <div data-bind="template:{name:viewModel().template, data:viewModel(), afterRender: viewModel().viewDidRender}"></div>
    <!-- /ko -->
```

In the app model, after the initialization, the view model is loaded.  Each view model has a simple template property which is a string that refers to the html template to render. The data item in the template declaration sets the knockoutjs context to the current view model.  The afterRender binding ensures that the ViewModel's viewDidRender method is called (with the container html element as a parameter).

This means I can do the following:

```
self.viewDidRender = function (parentElement) {
    self.containerElement = parentElement;

    $("html").on("click", function (event) {
        var elements = $(event.target).parents();
        for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
            if (elements[i] == self.containerElement[0] || elements[i] == self.containerElement) {
                alert("the target exists within the parent element");
                return;
            }
        self.open(false);
    });
};
```

There is a requirement that we intercept the html elements click event.  If the event occurred where the target was inside the parent element of the subview then ignore the event, else set 'open' to false (this is actually part of a light dismiss mechanism you see with PopOvers in iOS)

I am finding that when I switch between the two main views (the viewDidRender of this example view is invoked every time it's rendered), the body click handler above is bound multiple times.

I think this is a JavaScript memory leak.  Whereabouts should one clean up these bindings?  I can called $("html").off(...) etc... but where?  The beforeRemove event of the template binding does not invoke for a pure template item.... only for foreach bindings.

I *could* create another method within all of the sub-view-models like "viewWillHide", so everytime a new view is pushed into the ViewModel property of the app model, I could try to call a viewWillHide method on the view model.  This would work.  However, the application is more complex than I'm demonstrating here.  There is actually a hierarchy of view models and nested templates.

Doing it manually is an option; it does seem strange that there is not an opposite to afterRender of the template binding.

So what would you do?  A manual approach? Even though it would cause a cascade of changes throughout the view model hierarchy in order to propagate viewWillHide method down the hierarchy from the top (app model) down to the smaller view models.

Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using the knockout click binding in the  html in the template?  Then have your click handling in your viewmodel?  Sounds like a tricky problem though.

Comment: Yep, because the views models are transient.  It's only the concern of the view and the view model whether to intercept the click.  If you intercept click anyway, not only would you have to propagate it yourself from the app model level downward but also, something else would come up, so you'd be endlessly plugging concerns of specialised models into the app's more general architecture. I have just implemented it using a disposal pattern for now, which I'll post here if no-one has any insights which are better.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following code to unbind your jQuery events

```
ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function() {
    //Do cleanup
});
```

**edit: A little fiddle to demonstrate how to wrap a binding**

http://jsfiddle.net/d6cJG/

Problem is that addDisposeCallback on the div bounded to the template binding wont trigger a callback because that element never changes, its the elements inside it that change when template change.

Here callback will be called http://jsfiddle.net/d6cJG/1/

Comment: Unfortunately, if I register this disposal callback inside the "afterRender" method of the template binding, the disposal method does not get called when the template changes or the node is removed, even though I'm registering it against the element parameter that's supplied in the afterRender method arguments.  I don't know why.  However, it does look like this method is used in binding handlers, so I don't know if it's just geared towards that.

Comment: You should actually change tour code to use a custom binding. after render and before render intruduces DOM dependenmcy in your ViewModel

Comment: I don't think I can bind the html element to a view model that is transient, polymorphic and where the target of the binding may be n levels down in the hierarchy of view models unbeknownst to the html element declaration.

Comment: In your case its easy just wrap the template binding in a custom binding and abstract the render functions to that binding. I see no reason why addDisposeCallback wouldn't work outside a binding though.

Comment: Interesting... OK, I will investigate the idea of a custom binding for this